# Compare all cells in two rows between two ranges on the same worksheet

Tags: compare, rows

New to SO.

I am am looking for a code to compare all the cells in two rows that belong to two different ranges on the same worksheet.

The two ranges (data sets) are one below the other.

The values in column A between the two ranges are common.

The number of rows within the ranges can vary.

I would like a code to loop theough the ranges and compare each row based on the value in Column A  as a link and compare it to the respective row in the second data set.

If the values are different ,I would like to highlight  the row in the Second set / range if they are different from the first range.

I would really appreciate if you can help me with suggestions on how I can go about doing this.

Comment: What's your environment and where/what/when/how are you comparing?

Comment: I am in excel.i am trying to write a code in vba to do this comparion

Comment: Show some sample data, and show your own code. Also you can add `excel` and `vba` tags.